# new a File object, namely create a file in disk?

Tags: java, file, stream, io

when I new a File Object ,I found that there is not a file be create in disk,so I guess a File Obeject is not equal to a disk file, but when I write something to the `File` object through stream, I found the file be created in disk.

So, can I think like this, `new File()` - does not create a real file in disk, it is just an object in ram.  But when you write something to the `File` through stream, for example:

```
FileWrite stream = new FileWrite(file); 
stream.write(string);
```

..the stream will create a new file when the file does not exist (maybe function `steam.write()` does this?)?

Comment: Are you using Java 7 or Java 6?

Comment: `new FileWrite(file)`  (polite cough) By `FileWrite` DYM [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)?  If so, please be specific (copy/paste).  If not, please link to the docs for `FileWrite`.

Answer (score 1):

How about [`File#createNewFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29)? If you're using Java 7, you can also use [`Files.createFile(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29), as in [this example from the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html#creating).

Answer (score 0):

FileWriter creates or truncates the file as required. The write put something in it.  File is a file path name which may or may not exist. e.g. File.exists() is not always true and File.delete() can delete a file (i.e. the file no longer exists)